# Access to a session in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a session created in my vb.net codes and running some SQL queries, there are some local temp tables like `#T1, #T2 , ...`

Execution process has some steps and I need to know which data changes in my local tables in each step.

Currently I use this to view the data in my code:

```
 select * into ##T1 from #T1
```

I can't use `sp_getbindtoken` because there is no active transaction. I can not use `DBCC` because I don't have permission.

I can run `sys.dm_exec_sessions` view and therefor I have active `session_id`,
I also have `connection Index` of active `sql connection`

is there any way to connect to a active session and access local temp tables?

or is there any way to get those data of `#T1, #T2,...`?

EDIT1:

according to the comment which commented by @SeanLange

I have some temp tables as I said, and in the steps mentioned before I do some calculations on these temp tables, for tracing these calculations I need to know what happens in these steps, and I want to execute a simple `select` statement on these temp tables. what I wanted to do was connect to the active `session` created in my source code from an external project called `Tracer`, and perform `select` statements while my source is on the fly and meanwhile trace the data created in these session

Comment: Do you want to get data from temp table for different session?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda yes, those data are in a session created in my source code but I need to access them outside of my source code

Comment: If this isn't an xy problem I don't know what is. http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @SeanLange, I think you are right, I add some explanations to the original question, hope make my mean clear ;-)

Comment: Still don't understand what the real issue is here but to answer your question, plain and simple you cannot query temp tables from another session. If you could it would be a huge security problem. Sounds to me like you are trying to find a work around to not having the security you need to whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: @SeanLange I don't think it would be a security issue, because this is my created session and I access to 'spid','sid','kpid', 'sql_handle' ,... what I need is to trace the caculated data

Comment: Viewing data in a temp table from another connection is a MAJOR security issue. It doesn't matter that you created both sessions. The sql engine is not going to allow that, and I am glad they don't.

Comment: The more you discuss what you are trying to do this is the very definition of an xy problem. You either need to get permission to run a trace (or better yet use extended events) and/or get permission to add some logging in the procedures that are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it. Sorry. (at least without sa privileges).

Run your queries from within a stored procedure and add code to log whatever you need to a table, then query the log table as needed.

> Execution process has some steps and I need to know which data changes in my local tables in each step.

If you have permission, you can create a trigger to do the logging for you

Comment: I am doing this logging now, but I need to make a breakpoint in all steps and create some global temp tables to trace these data, what I need is to trace the live data and follow the calculated data

Comment: Normal users don't have this type of access. You'll need to install your own instance of SQL Server (the small version is free) and do what you want there.